# how to write contents in a word doc or pdf in c#

Tags: c#

how to write contents in a word doc or pdf in c#

like if i want to write some daily reports  generated into word doc or pdf  ..in unix we can just pipe the out put to text file can we do that in c# .i know that using string builder we can write the contents to text files can we write the contents to a doc or pdf format ?

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for a library that can write PDF files or Word documents, such as [Aspose](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/default.aspx) or [iTextSharp](http://csharp-source.net/open-source/pdf-libraries/itextsharp).

Comment: The following tutorial will give you a quick and dirty example of how to create a pdf using iTextSharp: http://www.developerfusion.com/code/5682/create-pdf-files-on-fly-in-c/

Answer (score 1):

You need something like iTextSharp http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/

Answer (score 0):

And if you want something smaller than iTextSharp to create PDF reports, try [Report.NET](http://sourceforge.net/projects/report/).